# is there any way to create a hyperlink inside tsv document?

Tags: php, excel, openoffice.org, libreoffice, csv

can i create a hyperlink inside tsv file ?

i just create a tsv document by using php's file writer function. but i don't know how t write a hyperlink in a tab separated value (tsv) file using php

this is the sample ts file that i created using php file writer function

```
cc  patNo   kc  patDate patTitle    appNo   appDate citedDoc
US  233072  P   _   _   US20090233072P  08-11-2009  _
US  8292232 B1  10-23-2012  patTitle    US20100854827   08-11-2010  _
```

please help me

Comment: A TSV file doesn't support any formatting of any kind, it's simply a set of raw data, so a URL would simply be a string of characters.... and there's nothing you can set in the file to identify it as a hyperlink, though any program reading your TSV file may have built in logic to recognise that string as having some meaning

Comment: If you need formatting of any kind, then you need to create a file format that actually supports formatting, such as .xls, .xlsx or .odc which is a more complex task that really requires a library.... you can do it yourself, but it's a large amount of work